# Change graph color in Plotly, Python

Tags: python, plot, plotly

Like we can change the color of the plotted graph in `matplotlib` using the `color` attribute, is there any way to change the graph's color in **plotly**?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi)
y = np.cos(x)

# this will create a blue line
fig = go.Figure([
    go.Scatter(x=x, y=y)
])
# to modify the figure after it has been created,
# explore fig.data and target the appropriate attribute
fig.data[0].line.color="red"
fig
```